# I have 10,271 attributes in a database I want to add them to magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, importexport

I have 10,271 attributes in a database I want to add them to magento 1 (inside an attribute group name "specification"), then import all the attribute values in each of the previous attribute fields. (depending on product sku they will be filled.

Comment: Hi @Sukumar Gorai

Comment: Generate as many attribute sets as you can. Otherwise the category pages will load in minutes. You have to create attribute sets for products by some criteria or more.

Comment: But I can't assign more than one attribute set to a product, isn't it?

Comment: One product has one attribute set. On a category page you'll have 20 products. That's mostly 20 attribute sets with attributes. Instead of loading all 10k attributes on a category page, it will load only tens of attributes. Performance will be a big thing for this store. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @obscure, that explained me a lot. Appreciate your help.